# Aligning text towards the bottom inside a square in a div in css

Tags: html, css

I have a screen-shot as shown below in which I was able to make the square and text in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nepgqcjL/3/embedded/result/).

[image]

The CSS codes which I have used in order to make the squares are:

```
.squares 
{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items:center;
padding: 1rem;
background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
flex-wrap: wrap;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.squares .square 
{
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
height: 200px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: rgb(145, 147, 150);
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I need to add in the fiddle and in the above mentioned code so that **text comes at the bottom in every square**.

I tried with `display: inline-block; align-self: flex-end;` but somehow it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`align-items: flex-end` only works on flexbox elements, and `inline-block` elements are block-level. Instead of `display: block`, you're simply looking for `display: inline-flex` on the child `.squares .square` (along with `align-items:flex-end`).

Also, note that if you want to horizontally center the text, instead of `text-align: center` you'll want `marign: 0 auto` on the `p` elements.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.squares {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.squares .square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(145, 147, 150);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.squares .square p {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="squares">
    <div class="square">
      <p>Franchise Hub Hierarchy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <p>System wide user permissions</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <p>Custom Corporate Branding</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <p>Configurable Workflow</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <p>Orders, C.R.M. and P.O.S</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have a similar [question](https://jsfiddle.net/nepgqcjL/4/embedded/result/). In it, the images are present inside the square. In this case what changes I should do in the CSS so that text come towards at the bottom and images stay at the place where it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
.squares .square {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I have asked similar question from Obsidian. I am wondering if you can have a look at it. Thanks. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nepgqcjL/4/embedded/result/) for it

Comment: Thanks, it looks great.